# JavaScript GPA form validator

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I am trying to create a form which will ask a sure to input name, GPA and phone number. I need help to validate the GPA to be a number between 0 and 4 inclusive, including at most two decimal values after the grade.
I cannot figure where to start!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

    <html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">
            function enter()
            {


                var grade = document.getElementById("gpa").value;
                if (grade >= 0 && grade <= 4)
                    { 
                        alert("success");

                    }






            }

    </script>
    </head>

    <body>

    <form id= "survey" name="survey">
        Name:
        <input type="text" name="fullname"/><br>
        GPA:
        <input type="text" id="gpa" name="gpa" maxlength="4"/><br><br>



        <input type="submit" onclick="enter()"/>





    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validate decimal numbers in JavaScript - IsNumeric()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-decimal-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, its written with just javascript and html.

```js
window.verify = function() {
    var gpa = document.getElementById("gpa").value;
    var ver = parseFloat(gpa);
    alert(ver >= 0 && ver <= 4);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="gpa" />
<br>
<br>
<button type="submit" onclick="verify()">Check GPA
```